# Binary search complexity for 10 elements is 0(log 10) = 1 , but the comparision required are 4

Tags: algorithm, search, data-structures, big-o, binary-search

The following set has 10 elements

```
{10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 40, 50, 56, 90, 100}
```

N = 10
O(log 10) = 1

if the element 20 has to searched then 4 compare operations has to be performed
(i.e)

```
1-comparision  10
2-comparision 23 (since mid value of 10 elements)
3-comparision 21 (mid)
4-comparision 20
```

How does Binary search has complexity of O(log N) ?.

Comment: Usually in CS, `log` is log base 2, not log base 10. But for Big O notation, the base is just a "constant factor" that's disregarded, anyway.

Comment: if you want to calculate efficiency in number, you need to read about combinatorics. recommend Algorithms by Robert Sedgwick

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Big-oh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) notation does not care about constants. In fact, it doesn't care about anything but the dominating term in an expression.

So even if your algorithm does `4 * log n` operations of a certain type, it is **still O(log n)**. As long as it is a constant times `f(n)`, the complexity will be `O(f(n))`.

For logarithms, the base is irrelevant because a logarithm in a given base differs from the same logarithm in a different base by a constant. This can be seen by the base change formula:

```
log_a(x) = log_b(x) / log_b(a)
         = [1 / log_b(a)] * log_b(x)
           \____________/
          this is constant
```

This is why the base is not usually specified in big-oh notation.

Notice that if you multiply the size of your input by an order of magnitude, making it `100` elements, you'd be doing `<= 8` such operations, which is `4 * log_10(100)`.

Comment: What is the **dominating term** in this example. Comparision operation ?.

Comment: @Talespin_Kit - no, the dominating term  is `log n` (multiplied by some constant). Comparison operations is just something that this term counts - it doesn't matter what.

Answer (score 1):

The order of complexity isn't really meant to be evaluated to an exact number in the general case.  Aside from that, the log being used is a binary log_2 of the variables, not a decimal logarithm.

Notice that you are halving the problem each time, not cutting it into tenths.  Admittedly, all logs in terms of complexity analyses are only a constant multiplier away from each other and thus irrelevant, but I think this cuts to your issue.

Comment: I think explaining it by using log bases just hides the real issue. For example, `log_2(10) = 3`, and then you'll have to explain why it's 3 and not 4 like the OP gets.

Comment: @IVlad: while I generally agree, in this case (regarding binary search, where the log base is known) I think it's fine to explain it by using log bases. `log_2(10)` is 3.3219... so it's easy to explain why it's 4: round up (because you can't do a partial comparison).